# Getting operational Error while processing django models

Tags: python, django

[Kept getting "Operational-error" message while trying to complete my first app model using Django administration.
Made some changes on my terminal & code editor but still yields same error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFZXR.png)

[The error loads up once I hit the save button. Please, what could be the solution?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d69KU.png)
[Here is the code on sublime text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXYhO.png)
[Same with this, after importing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4IZW.png)

Comment: Hi there, can you add the code and error messages into your question, rather than showing them as links. There is a code markup facility for you to highlight these elements of your question.

Comment: Alright
Below is the error message:
"OperationalError at /admin/products/product/4/change/
no such table: main.auth_user__old
"

Answer (score 0):

Have you make migrations yet,  if not,  write the following in your terminal  then click  enter

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Then when that is done,  write this in the terminal  too,  then click enter.

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Yes please, have already done that regarding migrations, but still same error message

Comment: Downgrade your django version by following 
these steps                                                            
                                                               pip install django==2.1.5
Delete the SQLite database (I mean the  sqlite.db)
makemigrations and then python manage.py migrate
Start the server with  python manage.py runserver